# How to implement a PUT correctly in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, jpa

Attempt to correctly implement a `Put`, according to `RFC 2616`.

> "The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the
> supplied Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to an already existing
> resource, the enclosed entity SHOULD be considered as a modified
> version of the one residing on the origin server. If the Request-URI
> does not point to an existing resource, and that URI is capable of
> being defined as a new resource by the requesting user agent, the
> origin server can create the resource with that URI."

In short, if the resource exists, it is modified; if it does not exist it is created according to the provided `id`.
Now I have such an implementation, `RFC 2616` states that when an element is created it must also return the location URI.
And I am left like this.

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Item> update(
       @PathVariable("id") Long id,
       @RequestBody Item updatedItem) {

   Optional<Item> updated = service.update(id, updatedItem);

   return updated
           .map(value -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(value))
           .orElseGet(() -> {
               Item created = service.create(updatedItem);
               URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
                       .path("/{id}")
                       .buildAndExpand(created.getId())
                        .toUri();
                   return ResponseEntity.created(location).body(created);
            });
}
```

The problem is that the `Optional`, so for good practices it should be consumed and checked in the services.
The other problem is the mapping of the entity, which should go in the service, but I don't know how to separate it if the URI location goes in between...

Any solution on how to refactor it?
Considering that the optionals are consumed in the service and the same with the mapping, but the URI goes in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `http protocol` rules are not strictly applied when it comes to implements `REST Api` with `Data Access Layer`. Lets say, in the case of `Spring Boot` or any another framework, the URI you execute just trigger a `Service` that access to your database.

The reality is that, you can even use a `GET` or a `POST` in place of the `PUT`, it will work.
Here, your resources is a database or your records (in your database), and your `http` calls don't directly interact with your database, but it is your `Service Layer` throught your `Spring Data Api`.

> In short, if the resource exists, it is modified; if it does not exist
> it is created according to the provided id

In this case this is your `save` method that will create or update your record.

I would suggest you this refactoring :

```
@PutMapping("/items")
public ResponseEntity<Item> update(
       @PathVariable("id") Long id,
       @RequestBody Item itemToUpdate) {

   Optional<Item> updatedItem = service.update(id, itemToUpdate);

   return updatedItem
           .map(value -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(value))
           .orElseGet(() -> {
               Item createdItem = service.create(itemToUpdate);
               URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
                       .path("/{id}")
                       .buildAndExpand(createdItem.getId())
                        .toUri();
                return ResponseEntity.created(location).body(createdItem);
        });
}
```